# Fixing Unicode error on checksum creation

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to debug the following issue I have in generating an md5 checksum for a string.

I have a unicode literal as follows:

```
>>>>> 129165Warner Bros.MovieESEn la Arena (Gira 30 Años y Un Día / Las Ventas 26 de Junio de 2015)2015SDBUYEn la Arena (Gira 30 Años y Un Día / Las Ventas 26 de Junio de 2015)1065227811https://itunes.apple.com/es/movie/id1065227811Live Not Avail'dOffer missing in availOpenLiveNo avail found-2TrueiTunes47160835 
<type 'unicode'>
```

However, when I try and do a checksum with the following:

```
hashlib.md5(string_for_checksum).hexdigest()
```

I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 47: ordinal not in range(128)

The odd thing is, when I copy and paste in the string it works fine, but when running "within the program", it always gives me the unicode errors. What may be causing this? Could it be perhaps a file encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode it into a bytes object first:

```py
hashlib.md5(string_for_checksum.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "copy and paste in the string" it probably isn't a unicode literal unless you explicitly prefix it with `u`.

In order to md5 something you need some actual bytes of data to hash. A unicode string is an abstraction representing specific sequences of characters without necessarily having one explicit numerical value expressed as bytes.

Thus you need to specify an explicit string encoding like `utf8` to convert the unicode string to a byte sequence that an algorithm like md5 can meaningfully operate on.

In particular, on Python 2 (which you appear to be using) the Python interpreter tries to automatically convert unicode strings to some byte encoding when an encoding is required. However, by default, it (usually) tries to encode to ASCII, so if the string contains any characters outside the plain ASCII range you'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Incidentally, if you paste non-ASCII characters into your terminal and try to make a plain string literal (without `u` it will often work because in this case Python will again automatically byte-encode your string, but using an encoding determined by your locale and other environmental sources.

In general, just convert the string to some specific encoding like `mystring.encode('utf8')`. Just make sure first it's an actual `unicode` type string before calling `encode()` and not a bytes `str` containing characters in some arbitrary encoding, or else you can get either `UnicodeDecodeError`s or [mojibake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) depending on the case.